# Invalid keystore format while trying to use sparkjava secure command

Tags: security, certificate, keytool, spark-java

I am trying to secure my web service that is running on Jetty.
The service was implemented using sparkjava v.2.3 which has a specific command for that purpose:

```
secure(keystoreFile, keystorePassword, truststoreFile, truststorePassword);
```

So, I used this command and generated keystore file using keytool utility:

```
keytool -genkeypair -keystore keystore.jks -alias $MYHOST -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -dname "CN=$MYHOST"
```

Provided a password and got the this keystore.jks file, however when I am trying to start my service I am getting the following exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:650) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:55) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.CertificateUtils.getKeyStore(CertificateUtils.java:52) ~[jetty-util-9.3.3.v20150827.jar:9.3.3.v20150827]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.loadTrustStore(SslContextFactory.java:1046) ~[jetty-util-9.3.3.v20150827.jar:9.3.3.v20150827]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.doStart(SslContextFactory.java:338) ~[jetty-util-9.3.3.v20150827.jar:9.3.3.v20150827]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) ~[jetty-util-9.3.3.v20150827.jar:9.3.3.v20150827]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132) ~[jetty-util-9.3.3.v20150827.jar:9.3.3.v20150827]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114) ~[jetty-util-9.3.3.v20150827.jar:9.3.3.v20150827]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.SslConnectionFactory.doStart(SslConnectionFactory.java:64) ~[jetty-server-9.3.3.v20150827.jar:9.3.3.v20150827]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) ~[jetty-util-9.3.3.v20150827.jar:9.3.3.v20150827]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132) ~[jetty-util-9.3.3.v20150827.jar:9.3.3.v20150827]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114) ~[jetty-util-9.3.3.v20150827.jar:9.3.3.v20150827]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:260) ~[jetty-server-9.3.3.v20150827.jar:9.3.3.v20150827]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:81) ~[jetty-server-9.3.3.v20150827.jar:9.3.3.v20150827]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:244) ~[jetty-server-9.3.3.v20150827.jar:9.3.3.v20150827]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) ~[jetty-util-9.3.3.v20150827.jar:9.3.3.v20150827]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:384) ~[jetty-server-9.3.3.v20150827.jar:9.3.3.v20150827]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) ~[jetty-util-9.3.3.v20150827.jar:9.3.3.v20150827]
at spark.webserver.JettySparkServer.ignite(JettySparkServer.java:131) ~[spark-core-2.3.jar:na]
at spark.SparkInstance.lambda$init$0(SparkInstance.java:341) [spark-core-2.3.jar:na]
at spark.SparkInstance$$Lambda$7/1326393666.run(Unknown Source) [spark-core-2.3.jar:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
```

IMHO the keystore.jks is valid, because certificate generated from it was successfully installed.
Investigating the problem further I am looking at the source code of the sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore and see the following code:

```
  645               int xMagic = dis.readInt();
  646               int xVersion = dis.readInt();
  647   
  648               if (xMagic!=MAGIC ||
  649                   (xVersion!=VERSION_1 && xVersion!=VERSION_2)) {
  650                   throw new IOException("Invalid keystore format");
  651               }
  652
```

Mentioned above constants defined in the same file:

```
   68       private static final int MAGIC = 0xfeedfeed;
   69       private static final int VERSION_1 = 0x01;
   70       private static final int VERSION_2 = 0x02;
   71
```

Now I am opening keystore.jks file with the hexdump utility and see at the top of it:

```
$ hexdump -C keystore.jks 
00000000  fe ed fe ed 00 00 00 02  00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01  |................|
```

So, based on what I am seeing xMagic variable is equal to MAGIC constant and xVersion is equal to VERSION_2. It should not throw this exception, but it does.

If someone can shed a light what I am missing here and how to make it work, I will greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I just checked a keyfile that is currently working and has the same hexdump in the first line you show, so there's not the problem.. Are you sure you are pointing write to the correct file location?

Comment: Yes I am. Otherwise it would throw FileNotFoundException or something like this. According to the stacktrace it does read those two integers from the DataInputStream.

Comment: Maybe you could put a breakpoint and see what the values are?

Comment: Cannot do that. This is not my code and JAR was compiled without -g option. I did find the source code on http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/security/provider/JavaKeyStore.java.html
BTW, are you using your key with spark-java or something else?
I was wondering, maybe this framework does something with the stream before calling JavaKeyStore.load().

Comment: I am using it with spark and works fine. Spark version is 2.3

Comment: Can you share the piece of code, where you are setting this SSL

Comment: Can you share a piece of code where you use secure command, please? Thanks.

Comment: `Spark.secure("/home/pmgomez/keys/private-key.jks", "pwd", null, null);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95619/discussion-between-pablo-matias-gomez-and-gary-greenberg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find the cause of the problem.
Keystore file was fine, but truststore was corrupted.
Unfortunately, it is uses the same piece of code for both checking and does not specify in error message which file it is.
That would be helpful if Spark development team in the next release include this info into the exception message.